# Charting a trend for tabular data using logarithmic regression

Tags: pgfplots

Given a few data points in a chart, namely the boiling points of the first halogens, I am expected to "predict" the boiling point of astatine. I was told that prediction does not have to be very precise, and virtually any estimation would be acceptable. I want my prediction to be as accurate as possible and devised a plan to use logarithmic regression.

The original chart is reproduced on the left. My prediction is on the right. The stumble block is how to extend the logarithmic trend all the way to astatine BP.

Here I got stuck. And my 2nd question is why does my 2nd graph not have the blue dots like the 1st one does?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,angles,quotes,intersections,decorations.pathmorphing,positioning,matrix,fit}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{bpdata.txt}
{Electrons} {Boiling Point}
18 -188
34 -34
70 59
106 184
\end{filecontents}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny,scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
grid=both,
grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
minor tick num=4,
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
axis line style={-triangle 45,shorten >=-10pt, shorten <=-10pt},
ymin=-200,
ymax=200,
xmin=0,
xmax=120,
]
\addplot table {bpdata.txt};

\node at (axis cs:28,-188) {\ce{F2}};
\node at (axis cs:44,-44) {\ce{Cl2}};
\node at (axis cs:80,55) {\ce{Br2}};
\node at (axis cs:116,184) {\ce{I2}};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{filecontents}{bpastatine.txt}
{Electrons} {Boiling Point}
18 -188
34 -34
70 59
106 184
170 337
\end{filecontents}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny,scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
grid=both,
grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
minor tick num=4,
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
axis line style={-triangle 45,shorten >=-10pt, shorten <=-10pt},
ymin=-200,
ymax=400,
xmin=0,
xmax=200,
]
\addplot[blue] table {bpdata.txt};

\addplot[red,raw gnuplot,smooth,dashed,domain={10,170}] gnuplot {
f(x)=a*log(x)+b;
fit f(x) 'bpastatine.txt' using 1:2 via a,b;
plot [x=0:85] f(x);
};

\node at (axis cs:28,-188) {\ce{F2}};
\node at (axis cs:44,-44) {\ce{Cl2}};
\node at (axis cs:80,55) {\ce{Br2}};
\node at (axis cs:116,184) {\ce{I2}};
\node at (axis cs:178,337) {\ce{At2}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did just one minor mistake.

Please have a look at the comments in the code for details.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
    \begin{filecontents}{bpdata.txt}
        {Electrons} {Boiling Point}
        18 -188
        34 -34
        70 59
        106 184
    \end{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{bpastatine.txt}
        {Electrons} {Boiling Point}
        18 -188
        34 -34
        70 59
        106 184
        170 337
    \end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        % you should use the new library instead of just `arrows'
        arrows.meta,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher so you don't need to prepend
        % every coordinate with `axis cs:'
        compat=1.11,
    }
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        font=\tiny,
    ]
        \begin{axis}[
            grid=both,
            grid style={
                line width=.1pt,
                draw=gray!10,
            },
            major grid style={
                line width=.2pt,
                draw=gray!50,
            },
            minor tick num=4,
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=center,
            axis line style={
                % that is the corresponding new name for `triangle 45'
                -Triangle[],
                shorten >=-10pt,
                shorten <=-10pt,
            },
            ymin=-200,
            ymax=400,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=200,
        ]
            % by adding the `+' sign all the default attributes from the
            % -- in this case default -- `cycle list' are used and the options
            % given are *appended* to these
            % (otherwise the default style not coming from a `cycle list' is
            %  used and the additional options are used)
            % because we have "measured" data here, I prefer not showing a line
            \addplot+ [only marks] table {bpdata.txt};

            \addplot [
                red,
                smooth,
                dashed,
                raw gnuplot,
%                % this doesn't do anything in `raw gnuplot'
%                % (besides that you used the wrong syntax. The separator is a
%                %  colon, so `domain=10:170' would have been right)
%                domain={10,170},
            ] gnuplot {
                f(x)=a*log(x)+b;
                fit f(x) 'bpastatine.txt' using 1:2 via a,b;
                % -------------------------------------------------------------
                % this is the part to answer your question
                % -------------------------------------------------------------
                % here you have to give the domain which should be plotted
                % I increased the end value to the value of the below given label
                % (and I increased the start value to 10. Change it back to 0
                %  to see why.)
                plot [x=10:178] f(x);
                % ------------------------------------------------------------------
            };

            % as stated above: now `axis cs' isn't needed any more
            \node at (28,-188) {\ce{F2}};
            \node at (44,-44)  {\ce{Cl2}};
            \node at (80,55)   {\ce{Br2}};
            \node at (116,184) {\ce{I2}};
            \node at (178,337) {\ce{At2}};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: nice in detailed explanation! (+1)

Comment: Did this answer you question or do you need further assistance? If it helped please consider -- besides [upvoting it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) -- [accepting it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: I wish I could upvote more than once!

Comment: @aiag, one time is totally enough ;)

Comment: @StefanPinnow Tried `-Triangle[]` with `arrows.meta` and it did not compile: `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '[' and I am going to ignore it. \draw[-Triangle[]`

Comment: I guess you have added that to the `\addplot` options, right? If so, you have to put it into curly braces. Otherwise you have (directly) nested square brackets, which is "not allowed".